# devise confirmation_url in HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, devise

My website is entirely SSL, so I would like to have also the urls generated by devise (3.2.2) for  Email verification to be `https://....`

currently the urls are generated by:

```
confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token)
```

which produces nice urls like:

```
http://example.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=zqfHS35ckLQZscSbsgMm
```

I would like the url to be

```
https://example.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=zqfHS35ckLQZscSbsgMm
```

Also, currently the email verification doesn't work, because nginx operates a redirect to the `https` equivalent to every page, and for some reasons things get messed up and the `https` version is a corrupted url, like:

```
https://example.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=zqfHS35ckLQZscSbsgMm?confirmation_token=zqfHS35ckLQZscSbsgMm
```

for some reasons nginx redirects to this corrupted url, so Unicorn can't but reject the request.

any clues?

Answer (score 5):

You can either specify the protocol in the email template, as you did in your own answer, or you can specify it as a default in the mailer.  The simplest way to do this, if you are happy for all emails to use https links, is to add it to your app config.  For example, in your production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:protocol => 'https', :host => 'example.com'}
```

I know it doesnt matter any more if you're going straight to https, but your url after the nginx redirect from http to https looks like it's appending the query string to the entire url, so it would be worth fixing that so it works in all cases even if you don't need it for the emails any more.  If you're using a `return 301 …` statement in the nginx config, perhaps there's a trailing `$query_string` or `$args` you don't need - for example, if you're using `$request_uri` that already has the GET parameters in it.

Also, I don't think you will find confirmation_url defined directly anywhere.  If you try `rake routes` you'll probably see one of them is:

```
user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:controller=>"devise/confirmations", :action=>"show"}
```

which means that there will automatically be a user_confirmation_url helper available as with routes in general.  I think devise then allows you to use confirmation_url due to its clever tracking of the scope you're using ('user' in this case), though I must admit I haven't looked at the code enough in devise's routing to know exactly how it does it for the routes.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the method call to:

```
 confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token, protocol: "https")
```

and that started generating correctly the urls with `https` as required.

I couldn't find the definition of `confirmation_url` anywhere in the devise code though.